# Document as unspecified/implementation defined

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have some typedefs which are implementation defined and I would like Doxygen to show this. I was sort of able to get this by using a Doxygen specific predef and just putting `unspecified` as the originating type, but the way it's formatted looks like a type which happens to be called unspecified.

```
#ifdef MY_DOC_GEN_DEF
typedef unspecified my_type;
#else
typedef /*implementation defined type*/ my_type;
#endif
```

Is there a better way to emphasize that this is an unspecified type?